# MySql - Alter Table and add column if not exists

Tags: php, jquery, database, mysqli

I have a mysql query where I'm adding columns to the table by altering the table but it throws an error `Error updating record: Champ 'rating' inconnu dans field list`

**Existing Table Columns**

```
id  int(11)         
script_url  text    
date    varchar(4)  
rateing varchar(4)  
photo   varchar(4)  
dateformat  varchar(4)
page_limit  int(4)  
proj_desc   varchar(4)
companyname varchar(4)
text_color  varchar(255)
citation_color  varchar(255)
bg_color    varchar(255)
border_color    varchar(255)
custom_css  blob
ratingsformat   varchar(250)
version varchar(250)
```

**Query**

```
$col = mysqli_query( $link, "SELECT proj_desc,companyname,text_color,citation_color,bg_color,border_color,ratingsformat,version,rating,customratings,speed,pagination,global_option FROM 'setting'");
if (!$col){
    mysqli_query($link, "ALTER TABLE  `setting`
        ADD  COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS `proj_desc` VARCHAR( 255 ) ,
        ADD  COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS `companyname` VARCHAR( 255 ),
        ADD  COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS `text_color` VARCHAR( 255 ),
        ADD  COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS `citation_color` VARCHAR( 255 ),
        ADD  COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS `bg_color` VARCHAR( 255 ),
        ADD  COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS `border_color` VARCHAR( 255 ),
        ADD  COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS `ratingsformat` VARCHAR( 255 ),
        ADD  COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS `version` VARCHAR( 255 ),
        ADD  COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS `rating` VARCHAR( 255 ),
        ADD  COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS `customratings` VARCHAR( 255 ),
        ADD  COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS `speed` VARCHAR( 255 ),
        ADD  COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS `pagination` VARCHAR( 255 ),
        ADD  COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS `global_option` VARCHAR( 255 ),
        DROP `custom_css` blob
        "
    );
}
```

**Error**
Error updating record: Champ 'rating' inconnu dans field list

What am I doing wrong.

Comment: Wrap off `quotes` form `table name` instead use `backtick`!! at `global_option FROM 'setting'")`

Comment: Why quotes for settings in select query ? remove single quotes from 'setting' to setting and please double check spelling of rateing :) it should be rating iguess.

Comment: why you are reversing the result (!$col), please check the rateing spelling. I mean in query nothing seems wrong except syntex query

Comment: rateing is a a typo done a long back and i can't correct that now. Thanks for the input i will try and let you know soon

Comment: Still the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have altered the code under for loop as all the columns are VARCHARS and using backtick worked out.

```
$col_arr = array( 
    'proj_desc', 
    'companyname', 
    'text_color', 
    'citation_color', 
    'bg_color', 
    'border_color', 
    'ratingsformat', 
    'version', 
    'rating', 
    'customratings', 
    'speed', 
    'pagination', 
    'global_option'
);

foreach ($col_arr as  $column_field) {
    $col = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT `$column_field` FROM `setting`");
    if(!$col){
        mysqli_query($link, "ALTER TABLE  `setting`
            ADD  `$column_field` VARCHAR( 255 )"
        );
    }
}
```

Let me know if this code is correct.